# Read last 3 months of data, transform and output

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pyspark and need some help.

I have data sitting in below partition.

[image: Data Source Partition]

- each time I run the script, I want it to only process pass 3 months of data.
- drop certain fields and only select few.
- Rename the fields.
- output to another s3 bucket in same partition name which was used to read.

How do I achieve the above.

I am new to pyspark need help to get started.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should work. Replace the `base_path` with your path.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Function to generate the last X months
def get_last_months(start_date, months):
    for i in range(months):
        yield (start_date.year,start_date.month)
        start_date += relativedelta(months = -1)

rollback=3
months=[i for i in get_last_months(datetime.datetime.today(), rollback)]
# Create paths required
base_path = "{y}/{m}/filename"
paths=[]
for i in months:
    paths.append(base_path.format(y=i[0],m=i[1])
df = spark.read.parquet(*paths)
```

The above snippet will help you in reading from multiple paths. The remaining logic is something you have to implement.